# Is there a way to remove S/MIME information from local Outlook via command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, microsoft-outlook, powershell

We have Certs installed for S/MIME signatures for all our Outlook users in our company. Is there a way to programatically remove the S/MIME settings on local Outlook clients so I don't have to do all clients manually?

What I mean are the settings in `Options > Trust Center > E-Mail Security > Encrypted email messages`. (translated from German but you probably know which ones I mean). I need them all in "factory default". Meaning no checkbox checked and nothing there.

I know I can remove the certs in local cert store e.g like this:

```
Get-ChildItem "Cert:\CurrentUser\My" | Where-Object { 
    ($_.Issuer -like 'SwissSign') -or ($_.EnhancedKeyUsageList.ObjectID -contains "1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.4") 
} | Remove-Item -Force
```

But outlook will still want to send the E-Mail with S/MIME signature because of the settings, but has an error since it can't find the cert anymore.

Is there a way to remove those settings programatically? It's fine if there is no cmdlet for this, I can also delete folders or registry keys or run VBA's etc.

I looked up command line options for `outlook.exe` [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/command-line-switches-for-microsoft-office-products-079164cd-4ef5-4178-b235-441737deb3a6#Category=Outlook) but it doesn't seem to have anything for my problem